# Cakephp mssql Store Procedure with parameters (Invalid cursor state)

Tags: sql-server, cakephp, stored-procedures, return-value

I use CakePhp for a little application. In this application I store some store procedures (I use mssql). Now I want to execute theses store procedures and want to use the result set.

If I call a store procedure without any parameters i get want I want without any problems. But when i call another store procedure with parameters i get the error "Invalid cursor state"). I did some research and i understood that there it seemed to be that i execute multiple select because of the result-state.

In CakePhp i call:

This is running without any problems

```
$res = $db->query("Exec storeProcedureWithoutParams");
```

Here I get the error with the cursor

```
$res = $db->query("Exec storeProcedureWithParams 'param1'");
```

The store procedures are very simple:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[storeProcedureWithoutParams] 
AS
SELECT [u1]
      ,[u2]
      ,[u3]
      ,[u4]
      ,[u5]
      ,[u6]
FROM [testdb].[dbo].[test]


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[storeProcedureWithParams] 
@test nvarchar(50)
AS
SELECT [u1]
      ,[u2]
      ,[u3]
      ,[u4]
      ,[u5]
      ,[u6]
FROM [testdb].[dbo].[test]
where [u6] <> @test
```

If I execute the both queries directly at the database I get two return. The first one is the result of the select-statement and the second one is the result-set. If I understood it right, is this the problem because i get two results (thats why the cursor-error). BUT I don't know how to solve it and I don't know how to get only the result of the select-statement without the return-state?

Can anybody help me?

Thank you very much!

Greetz

V

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, but I'll add it here for testing purposes, as there  aren't any full answers for this question.

Not sure 100%, but seems that when there is some kind of message output along the query results, it gives the "invalid cursor state". Adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` it solved to me.